# Eclipse can't find javaw.exe. Already changed eclipse.ini

Tags: java, eclipse

I have trouble starting a new eclipse distribution, that I downloaded from a server at work.

I extracted the folder to my desktop but running the eclipse.exe gives me the error: A JRE must be available. No java runtime was found at C:Users\my desktop\eclipse etc.

Of course it can not find the javaw.exe in the folder on my desktop as it is installed at program files. I already edited the eclipse.ini and added: -vm C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe

but it still gives me the same error so it searches for java in the wrong folder.

What should i try next?

Comment: `-vm` and the file path must be on separate lines in the eclipse.ini (and before any `-vmargs`)

Answer (score 1):

Your eclipse ini file should be like this:

```
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
...
```

-vm option on a line, path on an other line

Answer (score 0):

There is one more thing you can try 
Try setting PATH ([Details on setting path variable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html))

This way when eclipse starts, it'll find java. And if you continue to face issues, first check if you can access java from command line.